# What is the difference between stream_isatty and posix_isatty?

Tags: php, stream, posix

I am wondering what is the difference between stream_isatty and posix_isatty. I have also gone through with the documentation part for both as below:

```
stream_isatty: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-isatty.php
posix_isatty: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php
```

But unable to get the exact usages and differences between both of them. Can someone please help in understanding the same with an example if possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the documentation: `stream_isatty()` is a more portable version of `posix_isatty()`, since it works on Windows systems too.

Comment: When you want to do input or output to a file, you have a choice of two basic mechanisms for representing the connection between your program and the file: file descriptors and streams. File descriptors are represented as objects of type int, while streams are represented as FILE * objects. File descriptors provide a primitive, low-level interface to input and output operations. Both file descriptors and streams can represent a connection to a device (such as a terminal). Now you know the difference , **the above two functions work respectively for the two**